# Scala: How to automaticly call method when class is declared?

Tags: scala, class, methods, call

For example, I have a class like this:

```
class SomeClass(val x:Int, val y: Int) {
 def someMethod(a: Int = x, b: Int = y) = new SomeClass(x + 1, y + 1)
 override def toString = x + " " + y
}
```

And I want the someMethod to be called when I declare the class. And the someMethod should change values x and y.

So when I execute the code:

```
val sc = new SomeClass(2, 5)
print(sc)
```

I'll expect this result:

```
3 6
```

Can you please help me with this?

This is what I need but in c# :

```
using System;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        SomeClass sc = new SomeClass(2,5);
        Console.WriteLine(sc);
    }
}
public class SomeClass
{
    int x, y;
    public SomeClass(int x, int y) 
    {
        this.x = someMethod(x);
        this.y = someMethod(y);
    }
    int someMethod(int z)
    {
        return z + 1;
    }
    public override string ToString() 
    {
        return x + " " + y;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot change the values, since they are defined as `val`. `val` are defines a fixed value (which cannot be modified).

What you can do, is defining the received values as private, and define other values, incremented:

```
class SomeClass(private val xInternal:Int, private val yInternal: Int) {
  val x = xInternal + 1
  val y = yInternal + 1
  def someMethod(a: Int = x, b: Int = y) = new SomeClass(x + 1, y + 1)
  override def toString = s"$x $y"
}

val sc = new SomeClass(2, 5)
```

Code run at [Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/toshetah/BHpoFzPFQOuRy3PS1ESOEg/1).

Answer (score 2):

First, you want it to be executed when the class is instantiated not declared.

Second, if this would be possible in the general sense, it would lead to code that is hard to understand.

Third, it is not clear if you want to mutate `x` and `y` or just return a new value.

Fourth, if the latter, this would lead to an infinite loop and the code would never finish.

Fifth, why not just something like this?

```scala
final case class SomeClass(x: Int, y: Int)

object SomeClass {
  def apply(x: Int, y: Int): SomeClass =
    new SomeClass(x + 1, y + 1)
}
```

Comment: Hey, I specified what I need by the example in C#

Comment: @baltek99 First do not assume people will understand another language. Second, you want `x` and `y` to be immutable but mutable at the same time. Third, I do not know about **C#** but AFAIK it is not recommended to call methods during the constructor, the object doesn't even exists. Fourth, I still do not see why my suggestion of having your own factory method that does this for you doesn't work.